# Querying Relationship Existence using multiple MySQL database connections in Laravel 5.2

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, eager-loading, relationships

I am dealing with the following situation: I have two models, an `Employee` with `id` and `name` fields and a `Telephone` with `id`, `employee_id` and `flag` fields. There is also an **one-to-many relationship** between these two models, that is an employee may have many telephones and a telephone may belong to a single employee.

```
class Employee extends Model
{
    public function telephones()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Telephone::class);
    }
}



class Telephone extends Model
{
        public function employee()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Employee::class);
    }
}
```

The `Employee` model references a table `employees` that exists in database schema named `mydb1`, while the `Telephone` model is related to a `telephones` table that exists in a different database schema named `mydb2`.

**What I want is to *fetch only* the employees with *at least one telephone* of a specific flag *eager loaded*, using Eloquent and (if possible) not the query builder**

**What I tried so far *without* success is:**

*1) use the whereHas method in the Controller*

```
$employees = Employee::whereHas('telephones', function ($query) {

    $query->where('flag', 1); //Fetch only the employees with telephones of flag=1

})->with([

    'telephones' => function ($query) { //Eager load only the telephones of flag=1

        $query->where('flag', 1);
    }

])->get();
```

What I try to do here is first to retrieve only the employees that have telephones with flag=1 and second to eager load only these telephones, but I get the following **query exception** because of the different db connections used:

*Base table or view not found: Table mydb1.telephones doesn't exist* (this is true, telephones exists in mydb2)

*2) Eager load with constrains in the Controller*

```
$employees = Employee::with([

    'telephones' => function ($query) {

        $query->where('flag', 1);
    },

])->get();
```

This method eager loads the telephones with flag=1, but it returns **all** the employee instances, which is not what I really want. I would like to have a collection of **only the employee models that have telephones** with `flag` = 1, excluding the models with `telephones = []`

Comment: Just a suggestion, but maybe you could make a [view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/view-syntax.html) in one of your databases that merges the `employees` and `telephones` then pull from the view in your code. Also [see discussion on linking databases in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565993/oracle-database-link-mysql-equivalent).

Comment: Did you set protected $connection  = 'mydb2';  for telephones model?

Comment: @Froxz yes I do but unfortunately whereHas() does not take it into account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking into account [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14621943/laravel-how-to-use-where-conditions-for-relations-column), [this post](https://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-hasmany-relation-count-efficiently/) and @Giedrius Kiršys answer below, I finally came up with a solution that fits my needs, using the following steps:

1. create a method that returns a **Relation object** in the Model
2. **eager load** this new relationship in the Controller
3. filtered out the telephones of flag != 1 using a **query scope** in the Model

**In *Employee* model**

```
/**
 * This is the new relationship
 *
 */
public function flaggedTelephones()
{
    return $this->telephones()
        ->where('flag', 1); //this will return a relation object
}



/**
 *  This is the query scope that filters the flagged telephones
 *
 *    This is the raw query performed:
 *    select * from mydb1.employees where exists (
 *    select * from mydb2.telephones
 *    where telephones.employee_id = employee.id
 *    and flag = 1);
 *
 */    
public function scopeHasFlaggedTelephones($query, $id)
{
    return $query->whereExists(function ($query) use ($id) {
        $query->select(DB::raw('*'))
            ->from('mydb2.telephones')
            ->where('telephones.flag', $flag)
            ->whereRaw('telephones.employee_id = employees.id');
    });
}
```

**In the Controller**

Now I may use this elegant syntax a’la Eloquent

```
$employees = Employee::with('flaggedTelephones')->hasFlaggedTelephones()->get();
```

which reads like *"Fetch all the employees with flagged telephones eager loaded, and then take only the employees that have at least one flagged telephone"*

**EDIT:**

After dealing with the Laravel framework for a while (current version used 5.2.39), I figured, that in fact, `whereHas()` clauses do work in case of the relationship model exists in a different database using the `from()` method, as it is depicted below:

```
$employees = Employee::whereHas('telephones', function($query){

    $query->from('mydb2.telephones')->where('flag', 1);

})->get();
```

@Rob Contreras credits for stating the use of the `from()` method, however it looks like the method requires to take both the database and the table as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will work but you can use the from method to specify your database connection within the closure:

```
$employees = Employee::whereHas('telephones', function($query){

    $query->from('mydb2')->where('flag', 1);

})->get();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your answer but unfortunately that didn't did the trick. What you proposed actually selects a table named 'db2' which lies in the default database connection 'db1': See the error: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mydb1.mydb2' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `directorates` where exists (select * from `mydb2` where `telephones`.`directorate_id` = `directorates`.`id` and `flag` = 5)).

Comment: please see my latest edit, related to the usage of `from` method, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Dirty solution:

Use `whereExists` and scope for better readability.

In Your `Employee` model put:

```
public function scopeFlags($query, $flag)
{
    $query->whereExists(function ($q) use ($flag) {
        $q->select(\DB::raw(1))
            ->from('mydb2.telephones')
            ->where('telephones.flag', $flag)
            ->whereRaw('telephones.employee_id = employees.id');
    });
}
```

Then modify your query like so:

```
$employees = Employee::flags(1)->get();
```

Comment: thank you very much @Giedrius Kiršys, I have end up with the same query in order to filter out the flagged telephones (i.e. `select * from mydb1.employees where exists (select * from mydb2.telephones where telephones.employee_id = employee.id and flag = 1`)). However I also need to have the flagged telephones eager loaded.