# Eloquent whereHas Requires from() when Using Different Connections

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5, eloquent

I have two models - User and Announcement, and they exist on two separate connections - `mysql` and `intranet` respectively. The User model `hasMany` Announcements and the Announcement `belongsTo` a single User.

In the Announcement model I have `protected $connection = 'intranet'` and in the User model I have `protected $connection = 'mysql'`. Originally I wasn't specifying the `$connection` property on the User model as it is the default for the application but added it in for testing.

Doing any sort of query works normally. As an example these work:

- `User::find(1)->announcements()->where('name', 'something')->get()`
- `Announcement::find(2)->user`

However, when using `whereHas` on the Announcements model I get the following SQL Error: `Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'intranet.associate'` - `associate` being the User's table and `intranet` being the database connection specified in the Announcement model.

While I did find an answer to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36591148/4434366). I am curious, though, as to why you're required to use `->from(..)`. Is this intended functionality? I could not find anything in the documentation about using `from()`.

As a side note I was able to fix this "issue" by assigning the `$table` property in the `__construct` method in the User model:

```
__construct(array $attributes = []) {
    $this->table = env('DB_DATABASE').'.associate';
}
```

`env('DB_DATABASE')` being the default connection's database.